# Design pattern help: jQuery working with mutiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I'm new to jQuery. I wanted to know what's the best way to access the element when I am using the same element across multiple functions **in the same .js file**
Below are the two approaches I can think of. I have scoped functions ( F1 & F2) as well as other functions(F3,F4). I want to use elements in some or all of these functions. Whats the best way.

**Approach 1**

```
    var elm1 = $("#ID1")
    var elm2 = $("#ID2")
    var elm2 = $("#ID3")

    $(function () {

        function F1() {
            // work with elm1,elm2,elm3
        }

        function F2() {
            // work with elm1,elm2,elm3
        }    
    })

    function F3() {
        // work with elm1,elm2,elm3
    }

    function F4() {
        // work with elm1,elm2,elm3
    }
```

**Approach 2**

```
    var id1 = "#ID1";
    var id2 = "#ID2";
    var id3 = "#ID3";

    $(function () {

        function F1() {
            // get elements usings IDs
            var elm1 = $(id1)
            var elm2 = $(id2)
            var elm3 = $(id1)
        }

        function F2() {
            // get elements usings IDs
            var elm1 = $(id1)
            var elm2 = $(id2)
            var elm3 = $(id1)
        }   
    })

    function F3() {
        // get elements usings IDs
        var elm1 = $(id1)
        var elm2 = $(id2)
        var elm3 = $(id1)
    }

    function F4() {
        // get elements usings IDs
        var elm1 = $(id1)
        var elm2 = $(id2)
        var elm3 = $(id1)
    }
```

on other note, what terminology we use for functions F3 & F4? Global Functions?

Answer (score 0):

Approach #1 is the best of two, because you re-use the references to jQuery objects and you don't need to query the DOM everytime.

BTW, you should always use IIFE pattern (immediately-invoked function expressions) to scope these jQuery references and avoid messing the global scope (i.e. `window` object):

```
(function() {
   // Your code here
})();
```

> on other note, what terminology we use for functions F3 & F4? Global
>   Functions?

Yes, that's it. Or globally-scoped functions. Anyway, again, you should avoid messing the global scope and better use IIFE!

Comment: So why F3 and F4 is called global function even their scope is limited to that page only. I.e. only where the .js file is refrenced ?

Comment: @user3862378 I believe you need to study more about Web development! A page consist on HTML, JS and CSS. These functions are global because when they're already declared they're accessible from any script file

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: store a reference to the element in a variable or object property. More like approach 1.

Approach 2 is very repetitive and when it comes to maintenance will be a real headache.

Some suggestions on how you can improve approach 1:

1) defined your functions outside of the domready event event, then call    them inside the domready event. You don't gain anything by waiting to    define your functions/methods. But it is wise to hold off on    initializing them.

```
$(function() { /*do stuff*/}); //this is the shorthand for
$(document).ready(function() {/*do stuff*/});

var function1 function() = { /*do stuff*/};
$(function() { function1(); });
```

2) Remove everything from the global scope. I prefer to use an IIFE (see below).

3) Add a namespace (see below).

```
(function($) { //your local $ value is now a local reference, if you ever have a clash in the dollar sign globally, you don't have to worry working inside this function.
    window.namespace = window.namespace || {};
    var namespace = window.namespace; //local reference to namespace obj.
    namespace.elm1 = $("#elm1");
    //etc
    namespace.function1 = function() {
        //this == namespace. use dot notation to access properties/methods in this scope, i.e:
        console.log(this.elm1) //Object - the jQuery collection object
    };
    $(function() {
        namespace.function1();
    } 
})(jQuery); //pass the jQuery object into your scope
```

Comment: the reason I have global function because I have MVC Kendo widgets. and sometime I attach the events to the widget in Razor. If I attached scoped functions it doesn't work so I have to attach global functions eg @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Products>()        
      .Events(x => x.DataBound("F4"))        
    )

Answer (score -1):

First approach is better, not only when working with jQuery.